# getting rid of commits from one dev

Tags: git

I'm working with several other developers on a project and we are using git for version control.  All of us are git-novices of varying degrees.  For some reason one of our devs commits has been overwriting newer work - other devs will commit changes, everything is fine - this dev will commit a change and the new changes will be overwritten with his older version.  This is a topic in itself (and any insight is welcome).

My question is: How can I go through the history and remove his commits?  Would I use rebase? Cherry pick?  As I've said, I'm more or less a git novice and I don't have anyone with more experience to turn to.

Comment: Why this dev is overwriting other things isn't really possible to say without other information - maybe someone is doing a bad job of resolving merge conflicts, maybe this person is just making bad commits. Have a look at the history (use gitk perhaps) to see where the problem is, then if necessary, watch him commit, or watch someone merge his stuff, and see if they're doing anything different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [git filter-branch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-filter-branch).  Note that this may drastically change your tree, so have multiple backups first and verify the results carefully.

Comment: about having multiple backups - is this something I would create a new branch for and do there?  If I do that I'd have to get it back onto master - yes?

Comment: I meant back up the git directory at the filesystem level.  So that you don't have an emergency on your hands if your filter-branching goes poorly.

Comment: @JoeM05 You could do it in a new branch, applying filter-branch only to that branch, and even if you accidentally apply it to other branches, it does create backups of the previous positions of the branches... but since it's such a drastic operation, it's safe, easy, and clean just to do it in a completely separate clone.